# Remove "checked" from radio when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have a checkbox (`#FBmngCH`) that reveals a set of radio buttons (`name=adManage`) when clicked.  When the checkbox is unclicked, the radio button that was previously selected still remains checked. I would like to have the checked status of the radio button removed once the checkbox is unchecked.

This is being used in a form, so if the user changes their mind about selecting that service, I would like the details about that service to be wiped also (so the value of the selected radio will not end up in the PHP and ultimately the email).  I hope this makes sense.

I have given this some considerable time and am not seeming to get this to work correctly.  The last set of if-statements is the part of the code that I wrote.  Not sure if I am missing something, selecting something wrong, or what. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

HTML

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="FBchecks[]" value="Facebook Ad MGMT" id="FBmngCH">
    <label for="test">Facebook Ad Management</label>
    <ul id="FBmngList">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="adManage" value="Ad Management 1" id="adMan1">
            <label for="adMan1">Ad Fund - 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="adManage" value="Ad Management 2" id="adMan2">
            <label for="adMan2">Ad Fund - 2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="adManage" value="Ad Management 3" id="adMan3">
            <label for="adMan3">Ad Fund - 3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="adManage" value="Ad Management 4" id="adMan4">
            <label for="adMan4">Ad Fund - 4</label>
        </li>
        <div id="FBADerror" class="acctError"></div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS

```
$FBmngCH = $("#FBmngCH");
$FBmngList = $("#FBmngList");

//hide FB Management List
$FBmngList.hide();

//on FB Management select
$FBmngCH.click(function() {
    //toggle FB Management List
    $FBmngList.toggle();
});

$FBadValid = false;
$FBADerror = $("#FBADerror");

//if FB Ad Management is checked
if ($FBmngCH.attr('checked')) function validateFB() {
   $("input[name=adManage]").each(function () {   //LoopingthroughradioButtons
    // "this" is the current element(radio) in the loop
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $FBadValid = true; //Radio Button is Checked);
      }

      if ($FBadValid.attr = true ) {
            $FBADerror.empty();
      }
   });
};
if ($FBmngCH.blur($FBadValid.attr = false)) {
    $FBADerror.append("<li> Please select a Facebook Ad plan. </li>");
    //appends error to document
}   
if ($FBmngCH.blur($FBmngCH.not('checked'))) {
    $("input[name=adManage]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("input[name=adManage]").removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    //remove checks from radios
};  
$("input[name=adManage]").click(validateFB);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding your requirements, but can't you just test for this in your checkbox event routine and uncheck the checked radio button:

```
$FBmngCH.click(function () {
    //toggle FB Management List
    $FBmngList.toggle();
    if (!$FBmngList.attr('checked')) {
        $FBmngList.find('input:checked').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

See [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/uh8jr4fy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors in your code:

```
if ($FBmngCH.blur($FBadValid.attr = false)) {
```

This is not correct syntax. It should be:

```
$FBmngCH.blur(function(){
    if ($FBadValid === false) {

    }
});
```

Basically, since your're toggling the whole radios section and willing to remove their `:checked` property without checking any conditions, you do not need for loops or `if($(this).is(':checked'))` statements. Just remove `:checked` propery from all the radios. You can also show the error message on each check-box click, without `if` conditions, because the whole section is hidden anyways.

You should end up with very short code, like this:

```
$FBmngCH = $("#FBmngCH");
$FBmngList = $("#FBmngList").hide();
$FBADerror = $("#FBADerror");

$FBmngCH.click(function() {
    // no need for loops and if's there. Radios and the message are hidden.
    $FBmngList.toggle();
    $FBADerror.html("<li> Please select a Facebook Ad plan. </li>"); 
    $("input[name=adManage]").prop('checked', false);
});

$("input[name=adManage]").click(function(){
    // no need for loops there. Radios and the message are hidden.
    // Also, no need for if($(this).is(':checked')){. Since it's a click handler, something has to be :checked on radio click.
    $FBADerror.empty();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wcfrr6oo/)